# Generate WCF proxies as part of the build process

Tags: wcf, msbuild, proxy

I'm writing a WCF service which is going to be used extensively within our company, and I'd like to generate WCF client proxies as part of the build process and package them within an assembly so that clients of the service don't have to repeat this process on their end numerous times. Is there any way that anybody knows of to accomplish this ? Are there any pre-existing build tasks for MSBuild ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I wound up doing:

1) Create the project that has the service for which I want to generate client code

2) Create an MSBuild task that does the following:

```
a) Takes the compiled WCF Service assembly, runs svcutil.exe on it to extract XSD and WSDL metadata for all the services in the Service assembly.

b) Runs svcutil.exe again, this time on the extracted XSD and WSDL files to generate a .cs file containing the client

c) Run csc.exe to compile the generated client code into a separate assembly.
```

3) Insert the MSBuild task into the 'AfterBuild' target of the project containing the service.

Now every time I build the service, I get an automatically generated assembly that contains the client code that multiple other projects in our company can reference, without having to re/generate the same Web Reference in multiple projects. They can just reference a single assembly, and update more easily, having only to update one line in a project file rather than multiple files generated by the web reference generator. If anybody's interested, I can send them the code for the MSBuild task and the XML snippet for using it.

Comment: Could you post your code for this solution? Its exactly what I've been thinking about doing.  Like the post below, I've been using batch files and want to stop.

Comment: @aloncatz has roughly the right idea for executing the necessary commands in MSBuild. What I've done after my solution above it take it a few steps further, compile the assembly into a nuget package and then publish that nuget package to my company's internal nuget server

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to solve the same problem. Here's what ended up doing. 
In the .csproj, under AfterBuild target, add a task to fetch the SDK path, and use the Exec command to run the svcutil.exe. I had to use &quot; because the path contains spaces.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
   <GetFrameworkSdkPath>
       <Output TaskParameter="Path" PropertyName="SdkPath"/>
   </GetFrameworkSdkPath>
   <Exec Command="&quot;$(SdkPath)bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\svcutil.exe&quot; $(TargetPath)"/>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any built-in tasks, this is how I do it:

Create a project, generate the proxy class via svcutil and add it to the project.
Create an MSBuild script that (1) calls svcutil and overwrites the above class and (2) builds the project.

Would that not achieve what you want?

Answer (score -1):

Look at `T4` templating, and projects such as T4Toolbox

Answer (score -1):

Why not simply create a separate, class library project. In that project, use "Add Service Reference" for each of the services you need.

Other code can then simply use the classes in the class library.

Comment: Because that's incredibly manual, and I'd have to maintain that as a project. This way, I can have the client assembly generated automatically, I never have to maintain anything, and people don't ever have to go find the project and compile it themselves, they just already have the assembly, ready to use.

Comment: In what way is it manual, except when you initially create the references? You would only need to update them when the services change. Then, just deal with the output of that project the same exact way you deal with any other library code you've written.